# "Automatically Refresh Upon Sending" list function doesn't work

Tags: marketing-cloud, list, contact, mobilepush

In Salesforce Marketing Cloud, the button "automatically refresh upon sending" present in every contact list doesn't stay on after clicking on "Change" and setting it to "On". After the page is refreshed, the value goes back to off, has it ever happened to you? [image]

Comment: We have verified this behavior and a ticket has been opened to address this behavior in a future release.